# How do I assign the same auto-incremented primary key to 2 rows

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a table of orders with a composite primary key of `orderId` and `productId` for my attempt to assign more than 1 product to the same order/orderId.

So how may I assign the same auto-incremented orderId when I create an order ? This is what I have for now

orders model

```
const Orders = db.define('orders',
    {
        firstname: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
        lastname: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
        email: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
        phone: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
        orderDate: { type: Sequelize.DATE },
        orderId: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true },
        productId: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true},
        deliveryStatus: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
        productName: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
        quantity: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER },
        unitPrice: { type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(10,2) },
        amount: { type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(10,2) },
        address: { type: Sequelize.STRING},
        postalCode: { type: Sequelize.STRING},
        unitNumber: { type: Sequelize.STRING},
        notes: { type: Sequelize.STRING(2000) }
        
    });
```

routes

```
router.post('/checkout', ensureAuthenticated, async function (req, res) {
    let cartlist = await User.findAll({
        include: Shoppart,
        where: { id: req.user.id },
        raw: true
    })

    let firstname = req.body.firstname;
    let lastname = req.body.lastname;
    let email = req.body.email;
    let phone = req.body.phone;
    let orderDate = Date.now();
    let deliveryStatus = 'Order Confirmed';
    let address = req.body.address;
    let postalCode = req.body.postalCode;
    let unitNumber = req.body.unitNumber;
    let notes = req.body.notes.slice(0, 1999);
    let cardNumber = req.body.cardNumber;
    let userId = req.user.id;
    let idk = req.body.idk;

    for (var i in cartlist) {
        let productId = cartlist[i]['shopparts.productId'];
        let productName = cartlist[i]['shopparts.name'];
        let quantity = cartlist[i]['shopparts.cartlist.quantity'];
        let unitPrice = cartlist[i]['shopparts.price'];
        let amount = cartlist[i]['shopparts.price'] * cartlist[i]['shopparts.cartlist.quantity'];
        let imgURL = cartlist[i]['shopparts.imgURL'];

        Orders.create(
            {
                firstname, lastname, email, phone, orderDate, productId, deliveryStatus, productName, quantity, productName, unitPrice, amount, postalCode, address, unitNumber, userId, notes, cardNumber, imgURL
            },
            {
                where: { userId: req.user.id }
            }
        )
            .then((orders) => {
                for (i in idk) {
                    let result = Cartlist.destroy({ where: { cartlistId: i } });
                    console.log(orders.toJSON());
                    console.log(result + 'cart deleted');
                    res.redirect('/checkout/ordersummary');
                }

            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))

    }
```

These codes I have here simply create 2 different orderId and what I am trying to do is have different rows in my orders table with the same orderId but different productId when I check more than 1 item out.

All help is greatly appreciated !

Comment: `orderId` can't be `autoIncrement: true` if the same `orderId` will be in multiple rows. Generate the orderId outside of the sql insert? or normalise the data.

Comment: You can't, that's the whole point off auto increments

Comment: @Matt how do I generate the orderId outside ? Do u have any examples/references ? Thanks

Comment: @derpirscher any idea how I can do this order system without auto-increment then? Thanks

Comment: Fix your datamodel. Unless your system allows only one item for each order, the `Orders` table should not contain a  `productId`. But there should be a separate table which references `Orders` and `Products` and defines which products are contained in which order.

Comment: Also it should not contain customer data like first name, .... Make a `Customers` table where you store your customer data, and a foreign key from `Orders` to `Customers`. Better even, read some articles about basic database design principles ...

Comment: @derpirscher yes I will be planning to use include for the customer info and for the separate table, do u mean a table produced out of a many to many relationship?

Comment: Yes, because in fact there *is*  a many-to-many relationship between Orders and Products. Because one Order can contain multiple products, and one product can be contained in different orders ...

Answer (score 0):

The `orderId` column can't be `autoIncrement` if it will be used on multiple rows. The flat structure you have coded could have a standalone row that is the incremented primary key, call it `id`.

```
const Orders = db.define('orders',
    {
        id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true },
        firstname: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
        lastname: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
        email: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
        phone: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
        orderDate: { type: Sequelize.DATE },
        orderId: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER }
        productId: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER },
        deliveryStatus: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
        productName: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
        quantity: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER },
        unitPrice: { type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(10,2) },
        amount: { type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(10,2) },
        address: { type: Sequelize.STRING},
        postalCode: { type: Sequelize.STRING},
        unitNumber: { type: Sequelize.STRING},
        notes: { type: Sequelize.STRING(2000) }
    });
```

The `orderId` might be better served as a v4 UUID in this case, so the application can safely generate an `orderId` for insertion.

Notice that you would be duplicating a lot of these fields for orders with more than 1 product.

A [normalised form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) of this would create another table `OrderProducts` with the products for an order to avoid duplication

```
const Orders = db.define('orders', {
    id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true },
    firstname: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
    lastname: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
    email: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
    phone: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
    orderDate: { type: Sequelize.DATE },
    deliveryStatus: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
    quantity: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER },
    amount: { type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(10,2) },
    address: { type: Sequelize.STRING},
    postalCode: { type: Sequelize.STRING},
    notes: { type: Sequelize.STRING(2000) }
});

const OrderProducts = db.define('order_products',
    id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true },
    productId: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER },
    productName: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
    unitPrice: { type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(10,2) },
    unitNumber: { type: Sequelize.STRING},
});

// Setup the association which creates `order_products.orderId` field
Orders.hasMany(OrderProducts)
OrderProducts.belongsTo(Order)
```